# sort files by size error in c#

Tags: c#, file, sorting

I have a little problem sorting files.

My program should allow me to sort the files of a directory by size and by date. The date works fine but when I try to sort by size, it returns an error.

This is my relevant code:

```
if (orden.Equals("tam"))
{
    ficheroo = dirInfoo.GetFiles(filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(f => new FileInfo(f).Length).ToList();
}
```

the error is in the use of `new FileInfo(f).Length` and the error is:

> La mejor coincidencia de método sobrecargado para 'System.IO.FileInfo.FileInfo(string)' tiene algunos argumentos no válidos

This translates to:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.FileInfo.FileInfo (string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: could you translate the error message ?

Comment: Whats the error in english? FileInfo has invalid arguments?

Comment: @Sayse Yup - invalid arguments.

Comment: `GetFiles` already returns `FileInfo` simply put `f => f.Length`.

Comment: An error message in English would be more helpful, but from google translate it seems to be a quite standard error message. As you don't post the beginning of the code, it's hard to say, but you should debug and watch your `f` variable, which is probably wrong. It should be a string if I'm not mistaken... is it the case ?

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, that whase exactly the problem.

And sorry for not translate the error message, i have my IDE in spanish.

Answer (score 6):

[`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) already returns a `FileInfo[]` - so you don't need to convert each entry into a `FileInfo` using the constructor, as you're trying to do now. You can just use:

```
ficheroo = dirInfoo.GetFiles(filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   .OrderBy(f => f.Length)
                   .ToList();
```

(As a side note, it's worth seeing how using vertical space makes your code easier to read than having everything on one enormous line.)

Answer (score 1):

[`GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already returns `FileInfo`, I suspect you want

```
 dirInfoo.GetFiles(filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .OrderBy(f => f.Length).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compilation error because GetFiles already returns a FileInfo array. So you don't need to create new FileInfos in the OrderBy clause.

```
ficheroo = dirInfoo.GetFiles(filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(f => f.Length).ToList();
```